# Getting cpu name eg. QJZG, SR2HG etc. using linux terminal

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, sh

How to get the name of CPU using linux terminal, but not the name of a style `i3-6100`, but the name of a style `SR2HG` etc.? I mean the name that is typed on a cpu case and has capital letters and numbers.

### EDIT

I tried `lshw` command but not succeed
[image]

Comment: I'd suggest looking at the information that's available to the OS level at all -- look through `lshw` and similar. Once you know the information's available, if you hit a narrow, specific problem with bash itself or another programming-specific language or tool while trying to extract it, come back here and ask about that problem.

Comment: (Stack Overflow is specifically focused on narrow, specific problems with programming languages and tools; if your problem is "I don't know if any UNIX tool can access this specific information", you might want our sister site [unix.se] instead; they permit questions about non-programming-specific tools, which when our rules are strictly interpreted we don't).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy There are actually such questions on SO, but about ordinary cpu name, so u may be wrong.

Comment: Rules change over time (and, to be sure, are inconsistently enforced); in general, they're considerable more strict today than they were, say, a decade ago. If you want to know what the rules are right now, the canonical sources are [meta] and the Help Center, _not_ other knowledge base contents.

Comment: ...if we allowed precedent to control, it would be a swift race to the bottom: anything that was ever allowed (even by mistake, or because a questionable question got an excellent answer -- which is likely to save you here, since moderation guidelines cut against doing anything that removes good content, all else being equal) would be allowed forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First some terminology:

- QJZG, SR2HG and the like are called "Sample Specification Numbers" or "S-Spec numbers" or simply "SSpecs".
- i3-6100 and the like are "model numbers"
- A0, B1 and the like are "stepping" codes

The reason that `lshw` won't give you S-Spec numbers is that they are not readable electronically from the CPU chip.  What is actually readable are numeric codes that correspond to the model number and stepping.  In addition, the chip reports a "product" string that describes the chip ... as show in your `lshw` screen capture.

There is another Linux utility called `lscpu` that will also display the numeric codes for the model number and stepping, and other information.  For example:

```
$ lscpu
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              4
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-3
Thread(s) per core:  2
Core(s) per socket:  2
Socket(s):           1
NUMA node(s):        1
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
Model:               142
Model name:          Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-8145U CPU @ 2.10GHz
Stepping:            11
CPU MHz:             800.034
CPU max MHz:         3900.0000
CPU min MHz:         400.0000
BogoMIPS:            4599.93
Virtualisation:      VT-x
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           32K
L2 cache:            256K
L3 cache:            4096K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0-3
Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca
                     cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht
                     tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art
                     arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc
                     cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx
                     est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2
                     x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c
                     rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb
                     invpcid_single ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi
                     flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1
                     avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid mpx rdseed adx smap
                     clflushopt intel_pt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm
                     ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp
                     md_clear flush_l1d arch_capabilities
```

However, neither `lshw` or `lscpu` or (AFAIK) any other standard Linux utility is able to map the model and stepping numeric codes to their conventional textual forms.

And it is generally impossible to map a model and stepping to an S-Spec number.

Why?

Because the mapping is not unique.  There are usually at least two S-Spec numbers for any model + stepping.  One for pre-production samples and another for the production chips.

Even the Intel Support Site says that the only reliable way to determine the S-Spec of a chip is to look at what is printed on the chip itself.